# Get the latest date from grouped MySQL data

Tags: mysql, sql, date, greatest-n-per-group

I have the following data in my database:

```
|NO | model | date     | 
+---+-------+----------+
|1  | bee   |2011-12-01|
|2  | bee   |2011-12-05|
|3  | bee   |2011-12-12|
|4  | tar   |2011-12-13|
```

I want to get the latest date of each model group:

```
| model | date     | 
+-------+----------+
| bee   |2011-12-12|
| tar   |2011-12-13|
```

I tried:

```
SELECT model, date 
FROM doc
WHERE date ........????? //what is the next?
GROUP BY model
```

Answer (score 169, accepted):

Are you looking for the max date for each model?

```
SELECT model, max(date) FROM doc
GROUP BY model
```

If you're looking for all models matching the max date of the entire table...

```
SELECT model, date FROM doc
WHERE date IN (SELECT max(date) FROM doc)
```

[--- Added ---]

For those who want to display details from every record matching the latest date within each model group (not summary data, as asked for in the OP):

```
SELECT d.model, d.date, d.color, d.etc FROM doc d
WHERE d.date IN (SELECT max(d2.date) FROM doc d2 WHERE d2.model=d.model)
```

MySQL 8.0 and newer supports the `OVER` clause, producing the same results a bit faster for larger data sets.

```
SELECT model, date, color, etc FROM (SELECT model, date, color, etc, 
  max(date) OVER (PARTITION BY model) max_date FROM doc) predoc 
WHERE date=max_date;
```

Comment: I think the right sql would be： `SELECT model, date FROM doc WHERE date IN (SELECT max(date) FROM doc group by model)`, should add group by at last.

Comment: You'll need this if you have other column in the table. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/612231/how-can-i-select-rows-with-maxcolumn-value-distinct-by-another-column-in-sql

Comment: I was trying `SELECT model, date FROM doc GROUP BY model ORDER BY date DESC` but the order seems to be ignored here.

Comment: Consider what it means to group by model.  You're asking the query to consolidate multiple dates matching each model into one entry.  You need to specify a function like MIN(date) or MAX(date) to determine which one date to display from the many associated with model.

Comment: I recommend using `MAX(date) as max_date`, so that you can use `ORDER BY max_date DESC`

Comment: Using max(date) didn't solve my problem as there is no assurance that other columns will be from the same row as the max(date) is.

Comment: I added a third option because many comments throughout seemed to want to get at individual records instead of just a summary, and several wrong answers were posted.

Comment: You just saved me, I've been looking for a solution for a long time and I just needed to link the subquery with the query.
d2.model = d.model
Thanks a lot.

Comment: For the curious, an aggregate function will apply to each group created by a `GROUP BY` when it is present, or will apply to the entire dataset when a `GROUP BY` is not present.  I wonder, perhaps, if people are confusing a requirement of `GROUP BY` to include non-aggregate fields with a requirement to include `GROUP BY` itself.  In the subselect `SELECT max(date) FROM doc`, there are no non-aggregate fields to group by, so it is indeed correct to leave `GROUP BY` off.

Answer (score 21):

You can try using max() in subquery, something like this :

```
SELECT model, date  
FROM doc 
WHERE date in (SELECT MAX(date) from doc GROUP BY model);
```

Comment: As the `GROUP BY` is mendatory to get **all records**, this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Consider the dataset, `('foo', '2019-10-01'), ('foo', '2019-10-10'), ('bar', '2019-10-01')`  Using `GROUP BY` in the subselect would return an unwanted `foo` row for '2019-10-01' because it matches the same date as the `bar` max date.

Answer (score 17):

Subquery giving dates. We are not linking with the model. So below query solves the problem.

If there are duplicate dates/model can be avoided by the following query.

```
select t.model, t.date
from doc t
inner join (select model, max(date) as MaxDate from doc  group by model)
tm on t.model = tm.model and t.date = tm.MaxDate
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
SELECT model, date
FROM doc
WHERE date = (SELECT MAX(date)
FROM doc GROUP BY model LIMIT 0, 1)
GROUP BY model
```

Answer (score 0):

Using max(date) didn't solve my problem as there is no assurance that other columns will be from the same row as the max(date) is. Instead of that this one solved my problem and sorted group by in a correct order and values of other columns are from the same row as the max date is:

```
SELECT model, date 
FROM (SELECT * FROM doc ORDER BY date DESC) as sortedTable
GROUP BY model
```

Answer (score -3):

This should work:

```
SELECT model, date FROM doc GROUP BY model ORDER BY date DESC
```

It just sort the dates from last to first and by grouping it only grabs the first one.

Comment: this is not correct, if you GROUP BY model you have to apply an aggregate function on the other columns in select.

Answer (score -3):

And why not to use this ?

```
SELECT model, date FROM doc ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: you won't get the max or latest date using it. just sorting the date

Comment: If i sort the date in descending order and then get only the first one, then i have the newest date.

Comment: yes, of course. But what i want to do is to show the max date for each model. So i don't need to show a lot of record.

Comment: also, there's a nasty bug on mysql for "order by <..> desc limit 1"