# Get the last mod_date from MySQL data

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have this following data in my database

```
|NO | name  |exp   | mod_date          | 
+---+-------+------+-------------------+
|1  | dede  |  1   |2012-11-07 01:04:26|
|2  | dede  |  10  |2012-11-07 01:05:42|
|3  | GoGo  |  20  |2012-11-07 03:05:40|
|4  | baba  |  23  |2012-11-07 05:22:50|
|5  | baba  |  35  |2012-11-07 08:06:57|
|6  | baba  |  50  |2012-11-08 06:32:13|
|7  | rara  |  43  |2012-11-13 06:40:35|
```

I want to get the last update mod_date of each name :

```
|NO | name  |exp   | mod_date          | 
+---+-------+------+-------------------+
|2  | dede  |  10  |2012-11-07 01:04:26|
|3  | GoGo  |  20  |2012-11-07 03:05:40|
|6  | baba  |  50  |2012-11-08 06:32:13|
|7  | rara  |  43  |2012-11-13 06:40:35|
```

i tried this solution but it didnt work([same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8470311/get-the-last-date-from-mysql-data))

```
SELECT no,name,exp,max(date) FROM skill_exp
GROUP BY name
```

and i get this result from that query

```
|NO | name  |exp   | mod_date          | 
+---+-------+------+-------------------+
|1  | dede  |  1   |2012-11-07 01:05:42|
|3  | GoGo  |  20  |2012-11-07 03:05:40|
|4  | baba  |  23  |2012-11-07 05:22:50|
|7  | rara  |  43  |2012-11-13 06:40:35|
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea behind the subquery is that it separately gets the latest (*maximum*) `mod_Date` for each name. The result of which is then joined back to the original table to get other columns in each row.

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    tableName a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT name, MAX(mod_date) maxDate
            FROM tableName
            GROUP BY name
        ) s ON  a.name = s.name AND
                a.mod_date = s.maxDate
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/07162/1)

Comment: yeah i forgot to try this way join the original table thanks sir

Answer (score 1):

One more simple way with `SELF JOIN`

```
select max(t1.no) NO,t1.name,max(t1.exp),max(t1.mod_date) from tablename t1
inner join tablename t2
on t1.name=t2.name
where t1.mod_date>=t2.mod_date
group by t1.name order by t1.No
```

[**SQL_LIVE_DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/07162/33)