# MySQL how to get all the rows of latest date from database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table "rdv" like this
[image: table]

I want to select all the rows of the lastest date, in this case, the 3 rows of 2017-04-29, I tried the query from [Get the latest date from grouped MySQL data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8470311/get-the-latest-date-from-grouped-mysql-data), but it can only select the last one rows
[image: one rows selected]
So how to select all the rows of the lastest date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the condition. You need to change the datetime to date

```
select *
from rdv
where date (date_creation) in (
        select date (max(date_creation))
        from rdv
        )
```

Comment: It's my bad, I didn't see the DATE before max, now it's good, it works, great, thx !!

Comment: @JiangLan have you added the `DATE` method on `date_creation` just like the answer?

Comment: just as your said, I forget that, now it's done

Comment: @JiangLan  Glad i could help.

Answer (score 0):

Use **DATE** function to get only date of timestamp and **CURDATE** function to get current date

SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE DATE(`date_field`) = CURDATE()

Comment: I didn't tried this but thanx for your help

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
select * from rdv having date_creation in (select max(date_creation) from rdv)
```

or try this

```
    select * from rdv having date_creation = (select max(date_creation) from rdv)
```

Comment: I tried this but it returns the same single row, I know now, need to convert the Datetime to Date, this will work, `SELECT * FROM rdv WHERE DATE(date_creation) IN (SELECT DATE(max(date_creation)) FROM rdv)`

Comment: Please tell me if it Works

Comment: @ Anshul I tried your query but it returns only one row cause it's the max datetime, so I convert it to date, I add DATE base on your query, then it works `select * from rdv having DATE(date_creation) in (select DATE(max(date_creation)) from rdv)`