# getting all records with latest date [ERROR]

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table that I want to return the firstname and fathername of all the records with the latest data ,should be dynamic whenever a new latest date is inserted to return that record. 
I've tried this

```
SELECT rh.firstname, rh.fathername, rh.bloodonation_date
FROM personprofile rh,
  (SELECT MAX(bloodonationdate) AS maxdate, firstname
   FROM report_history
   GROUP BY firstname) maxresults
WHERE rh.firstname= maxresults.firstname
AND rh.bloodonation_date= maxresults.bloodonation_date;
```

So if I have this table

```
firstname, fathername,bloodonation_date
--------------------------
Ahmed     issa   2018-12-24
Noora     issa   2018-12-21
Joseph    John   2018-12-24
Ash       Scott  2018-12-24
Isacf     jaack  2018-12-24
Ashley    Make   2018-12-24
James     Ma     2018-12-20
cd        cd     2018-12-24
cde       cde    2018-12-24
Marc      Mac    2018-12-16
Noora     Ahmed  2018-12-15
Rabeew    fbdb   2018-11-15
```

How do I get it to return

```
firstname, fathername,bloodonation_date
--------------------------
Ahmed     issa   2018-12-24
Joseph    John   2018-12-24
Ash       Scott  2018-12-24
Isacf     jaack  2018-12-24
Ashley    Make   2018-12-24
cd        cd     2018-12-24
```

Comment: What's your dbms?

Comment: My database is mysql

Comment: Why didn't you expect show `cde       cde    2018-12-24` row?

Comment: I forgot to put it but it shoukd be there

Comment: Ok you can try my answer :)

Comment: Please stop using comma based Implicit joins and use [Explicit `Join` based syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5654278/2469308)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the latest date from grouped MySQL data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8470311/get-the-latest-date-from-grouped-mysql-data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a sub query here:

select * from personprofile where 
bloodonation_date=(select max(bloodonation_date) from personprofile)
order by 1 
, [Check solution here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f3faa0c/1/0)

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use correlate subquery.

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE T(
   firstname VARCHAR(50),
    fathername VARCHAR(50),
bloodonation_date DATE
);



INSERT INTO T VALUES ('Ahmed','issa','2018-12-24');
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('Noora','issa','2018-12-21');
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('Joseph','John','2018-12-24');
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('Ash','Scott','2018-12-24');
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('Isacf','jaack','2018-12-24');
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('Ashley','Make','2018-12-24');
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('James','Ma','2018-12-20');
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('cd','cd','2018-12-24');
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('cde','cde','2018-12-24');
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('Marc','Mac','2018-12-16');
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('Noora','Ahmed','2018-12-15');
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('Rabeew','fbdb','2018-11-15');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT *
FROM T 
WHERE bloodonation_date = (
  SELECT  MAX(bloodonation_date) 
  FROM T                       
);

| firstname | fathername | bloodonation_date |
| --------- | ---------- | ----------------- |
| Ahmed     | issa       | 2018-12-24        |
| Joseph    | John       | 2018-12-24        |
| Ash       | Scott      | 2018-12-24        |
| Isacf     | jaack      | 2018-12-24        |
| Ashley    | Make       | 2018-12-24        |
| cd        | cd         | 2018-12-24        |
| cde       | cde        | 2018-12-24        |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/m5t67FAmAC46oEdj5db7dS/1)

Comment: just did that also. would like to add, that I found that DB fiddle site to be useful and will bookmark it for future use.